# Write a Proxy Server in .NET (C# or VB.NET)?

Tags: .net, proxy

I'm looking to write a simple proxy server in .NET. Does anyone have any good examples they could post here, or just a link?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710379/http-proxy-server-in-c.

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but the accepted answer on the other question doesn't actually provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of searching turned up [this open source implementation](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/).

**Disclaimer:** *I have never used this software so I don't know anything about it other than it may be a good place to start reading example code.*

Comment: This seems to be the only one out there. Too bad.