# Proxy connection while browser is running

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, registry

I have to make application that will connect/disconnect to proxy server even while browser is running. I found out that I can change some registry keys value.
Here is my code in Visual Basic:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1

Public Sub SetProxy() 
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim regkey1 As RegistryKey
    regkey1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default)
    regkey1.SetValue("ProxyServer", "ftp=10.8.0.1:808;http=10.8.0.1:808;https=10.8.0.1:808;socks=10.8.0.1:1080", RegistryValueKind.Unknown)
    regkey1.SetValue("ProxyEnable", True, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    regkey1.Close()

    Label1.Text = "Connected to Disa's Proxy Server"
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    On Error Resume Next


    SetProxy() 
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim regKey As RegistryKey
    regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default)
    regKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", False, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    regKey.Close()

    Label1.Text = "Disconnected from Disa's Proxy Server"
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
End Sub
End Class
```

This code works well on Firefox, but doesn't on IE and Chrome. 
While IE is opened it prevents all registry changes in `Internet Settings`. Chrome needs restart or opening the Proxy settings to reload proxy information.
How to force browers to reload proxy configuration?

**EDIT**
Example: [ChrisProxy](http://www.chris-pc.com/proxy/)

Comment: I suspect there won't be an easy answer for this, presumably Chrome is only loading the settings on load which is exactly how I would have done it. Maybe you could change your code so that your proxy can be used all the time, but normally does nothing?

Comment: I don't want to use proxy all the time. F.e I want to browse some pages via proxy and download files without. That's why I want to be able to change it rapidly like Firefox does. The problem is that I usually don't use FF.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of write your own local proxy server so it might use the default settings and have a way to flip to a different server as required. Anyway see how you go for answers, maybe I'm missing something but don't think this will easily be achieved across browsers without either doing that, something browser specific or something at a much lower level on the network stack.

Comment: This IP is IP of my server connected through VPN

Comment: You could have a proxy on 127.0.0.1 (local machine) that swaps between them though, as in a proxy of your own design. Interesting question though and I look forward to seeing other ideas / solutions.

Comment: @PeterJ This local machine proxy idea seems interesting. Can you tell something more, or link?

Comment: I've never actually written one, but check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106372/write-a-proxy-server-in-net-c-or-vb-net. The code linked in the answer is C# but might give you a few ideas. It's a fairly complex undertaking though if you've never done much network programming.

Comment: Well, I installed some proxies applications and found out that all of them don't require restarting of any browser.

Comment: @Disa How are you connecting to the Web Browser. Can you not use System.Net.WebClient to connect which would allow you to specify a System.Net.WebProxy.

Comment: @Sorceri Could you post sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should call, in your program:**

```
InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0);
     // Notifies the system that the registry settings have been changed
     // so that it verifies the settings on the next call to InternetConnect.

InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH , NULL, 0);
     // Causes the proxy data to be reread from the registry for a handle. 
     // No buffer is required.
```

With that code, no need to restart or opening the proxy settings to reload proxy information. Existing  Chrome and Internet Explorer instances are notified by INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED and INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH.

---

**Notes:**

1. Your calling program can't be a service. InternetSetOption() is a WinINet call.
2. It should run under the same-user (as of the browser) account.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize WebClient to connect and set a proxy.  A very simple example is shown below.

```
Sub GetWebPageWithProxy(ByVal pathToUrl As String, ByVal pathToSaveFile As String)
    Dim wc As WebClient
    wc = New WebClient
    wc.Proxy = New WebProxy(New Uri("http://10.8.0.1:808"))
    wc.DownloadFile(pathToUrl, pathToSaveFile)
End Sub
```

Comment: I could programm my 'own browser' that will use my proxy with this code, right? I just want to force reloading proxy setting in Chrome and IE

Comment: Yes you could hence what are you trying to really accomplish, why the need for the browser to be open?  Read up here on changing on the Fly. (for IE) Not sure about the others http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3651/Change-Internet-Proxy-settings

Comment: This link is very useful. Thanks