# How to develop a proxy server using DotNet?

Tags: c#, .net

Hai 
 I am Developing an Windows application using C#.Net where I have to block certain websites from accessing by the user.So I am trying to develop a proxy server which can block the websites.Can some one suggest me how I can do this with an example or a site which can help me.

Thank you
Chaithu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these links:

http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/

[HTTP Proxy server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710379/http-proxy-server-in-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/reverseproxy.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/web_proxy11162005001036AM/web_proxy.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asproxy.aspx